# The click events for my ipad app stops working after some time using it

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ipad, mobile

All click events are working like they should for some time but then when I click the "GROUPS > YOUNG PEOPLE" input I get a skip to the first page(I might add that this input doesn't even have a link attached to it) all of a sudden and the click events for the group links stops working. 
I can still create new groups but can't click any links. I am using jquery mobile and phonegap along with DOM to get the groups and people from the groups. Also using Web SQL to store/fetch data locally.

[image]

It's working like it should on desktop, it only happens for the ipad and iphone.

> Fetch all groups:

```
var gruppidn = [];
 db.transaction(function(transaction) { 
   transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM grupp;', [], 
     function(transaction, result) { 
      if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
        var inn = "<ul id='ulitems'>"; //
        for (var t = 0; t < result.rows.length; t++) { 
            var row = result.rows.item(t); 
            grupper.push(row.FirstName);
            localStorage.setItem(row.UserId+"namn", row.FirstName);
            inn += "<li data-icon='plus'><a id='gruppen"+t+"' href='#page2' class='fikon' onClick='' data-transition='none'><div style='height: 50px;background: #396B9E;padding: 10px;width:0px;float:Left;'>";
            inn += "<img src='img/hands.png' width='30' height='30' style='margin-left:20px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -18px'/></div><h2 style='margin-top:0px'>" + row.FirstName+ "</h2></a></li>";
            gruppidn.push(row.UserId);
       }
            inn += "</ul>";
            $('#lbUsers').html(inn);
            for (var p = 0; p < gruppidn.length; p++) { 
                grupperclickevents(p, gruppidn[p]);
            }
            gruppidn = [];
      } 
     },errorHandler); 
 },errorHandler,nullHandler); 


 return; 
}
```

> Adding of click event to all DOM objects(groups)

```
function grupperclickevents(listid, gruppid){
$("#gruppen"+listid).off();
$("#gruppen"+listid).on('click', function(event) {




fetchperson(gruppid);

        $.mobile.changePage( "#page2", { transition: "none", changeHash: false });
              // this fires once on all devices
            });

}
```

> If click on a group = fetchperson function activates and all people
>   of that group gets returned

```
function fetchperson(idofgroup){

    var dnam = localStorage.getItem(idofgroup+"namn");
    localStorage.setItem("opengroup", idofgroup);
    Listpersonofg(idofgroup);
    //console.log(idofgrupp);
    $('#namn').html(dnam);
}
```

And then to the button that introduces the error (works fine first times you use it, it's when you have used the page for a while and code is stored on the client)

```
 $('#page2').on('pageinit', function() {
    $( "#klicksel" ).off();
    $("#klicksel").on('touchend click', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
            selectwinner(1);
      // this fires once on all devices
    });
//below is if you add a new person, an input field first appears
$( "#clickd" ).off();
     $("#clickd").on('touchend click', function () {
     if(noaddp == true){
            toggleinputfield();
            }
    });

//enter on input to add new person (below)
    $('#newadd2').on('keyup', function(e) {
        var pername = $("#newadd2").val();
        var svalue = $(this).val();
        if (e.which == 13) {

            if(pername == ""){
                console.log("Skriv in ett namn");
            }else{
                var opengr = localStorage.getItem("opengroup");
                AddPersonToGroup(opengr);
            }
            toggleinputfield();
        }
    });
});
var noaddp = true;
 function toggleinputfield(){
     if(noaddp == true){
        noaddp = false;
        $("#newadd2").css({"display":"block"});
        $("#addpeep").css({"display":"none"});          
        document.getElementById("newadd2").focus();
     }else{
        $("#newadd2").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#addpeep").css({"display":"block"}); 

        noaddp = true;       
     }


 }
```

> HTML

```
<div data-role="page" class="container" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-bar ui-bar-b">
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">   
        <article style="position:relative">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" id="click"><h1 id="newg"><span id="addgriup">Add Group</span><input type="text" maxlength="25" placeholder="Group Name" id="newadd"/></h1></li>
            </ul>

        </article>
            <div id="lbUsers">
        <div id="status"></Div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p style="text-align:center">&copy; Christopher Jubell 2016</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" class="container" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-bar ui-bar-b">

            <a href="#page1" style="z-index:100;" id="deletegrupp" data-icon="delete" data-transition="none">Delete</a>
                <a href="#page1" style="z-index:100;" data-icon="home" data-transition="flip">Groups</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <article>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" id="clickd"><h1 id="newg"><span id="addpeep">Groups > <span id="namn"></span></span><input type="text" maxlength="25" placeholder="Name" id="newadd2"/></h1></li>
            </ul>

        </article>
        <div id="lbdelt">
        <div id="status"></Div>
    </div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>Who can Pray? Click the icon</h1>
        <div class="centert"><a id="klicksel" data-role="button"><div class="circledot">
            <img src="img/hands.png" width="30" height="30" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -18px; margin-top: -18px"/></div></a></div>
        <p style="text-align:center">&copy; Christopher Jubell 2016</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried writing "onclick" with DOM, didn't work either

Comment: Hmm... I'm not overly familiar with PhoneGap. Do you have a debugger available that you can use on your phone while the application is running? Also, is there any way you can reduce the amount of code and still get the same error?

Comment: Its usually a good idea to spend some time removing all details not directly contributing to the problem before posting on SO. Most people won't read your question if you post too much code. ;-)

Comment: I don't unfortunately, I added alerts to the clickable groups and they still fired off but they don't take me to page 2... Yeah, I have to look up what kind of debugger I can use with an ipad, would help alot. 
I Guess I can try and reduce the amout of code, it's just that I don't know what I'm looking for really, and it takes a while to get the code ready for testing on the ipad. I continue digging. Hmm, tricky.

Comment: True, I included a bit too much code since I'm unsure where this error is even coming from. But yeah :P

Comment: A common problem-solving strategy used when programming is called "Divide and Conquer". There is a formal algorithm solving strategy with that name, but it resembles a lot to that which a lot of programmers do to find bugs.

The basic idea is to remove code until there is nothing left to remove, while the bug still being present. When there is nothing left you can remove without removing the bug, you should get a good hunch on what is causing the bug. Might help you if you don't get the debugger up and running. ;-)

Comment: And by the way, hunting bugs may often require a lot of time. I have a co-worker who has been working on finding and eliminating single bugs in our desktop client for more than 40 hours. There are ways to reduce the risk of producing bugs in the first place by following some set of software best-practices.